# Reuse Facebook Access Token from Android API to login a remote server

Tags: android, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an Android App that requires users to log-in by their Facebook (so we can get their profile picture and albums). It works great by using the Android Facebook API. After I get the access token from the API, I can get the information that I want and also post feeds/photos by the App.

However, I now need to build the remote function for this App as well, which means the App should talk to our server for managing his own information and fetch other information.

I plan to manage users in our server by also the Facebook API. Specifically, I am using .net + Facebook authentication:
[.net Facebook authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x)
It works ok. Basically, when people(or my App) visit the url on our server, a response from Facebook will ask user to log-in and then my server can get user's identity.

My problem is, in this case, the users seem to handle the log-in "twice" (one for Android Facebook API and one for remote server Facebook API). Is there any way that I can just do it once? For example, once I get the "access token" by the Android Facebook API, can I pass that "access token" to my remote server (maybe via the post header?), and then my server will be able to talk to Facebook via the same log-in identify. (I prefer using the Android SDK because it allows users to skip entering the password if the user has the Facebook app installed)

I am wondering if anyone can give me some suggestions to achieve this function. I notice there is something called "JWT Bearer Token" seems fit my need but I am still looking for tutorials of using this with Facebook API.

Comment: Yes, pass token from client to server, and then use token to make server-side API calls. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#tokenhijacking

Comment: Hi, I found this tutorial actually explains everything in this situation: https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/social-signin-spa-jwt-server.html